# How do I prevent overlap of rows CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, canvas

I just started working with css grids. I am trying to read a pdf in web browser where each page is rendered in a new canvas element. Canvas elements are added dynamically depending upon the number of pages in the pdf file. I am using grid display, but the different pages (canvas elements) come out overlapped, as shown here:
[overlapped messed up rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogAzZ.png)

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="pdfHolder" id="pdfHolder">
    <canvas id="cvsPg1" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvsPg2" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvsPg3" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvsPg4" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvsPg5" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvsPg6" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvsPg7" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvsPg8" class="canvasPage" height="1052" width="743"></canvas>
</div>
```

And here is the corresponding CSS:

```css
.pdfHolder {
    display: grid;
    min-width: 500px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.canvasPage {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If I don't use the grid display for the pdfHolder element, it comes out fine (scrolling list of 8 canvas elements one after the other).
If I add `grid-auto-rows: 1100px;` i.e. explicitly setting row height, it works. But now I see a big gap between the canvas elements: [big gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvQCZ.png)

I doubt if it will work everytime (e.g. on a different screen etc, or with another pdf with a different page size etc.). Is there a way to implicitly set the row height depending upon the canvas height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canvas have `height="1052"` did you try to use `grid-auto-rows: 1052px;` or `grid-auto-rows: max-content;` and `gap: 0;`

Comment: Yes. 1052+anything will give me the correct layout. But my concern is what if a user tries reading a pdf with only, say 512px, and then they will see a gap of 541px. auto does not work and still gives me overlapped elements.

Comment: Ahh.. Did You try with `max-content`?